# Try Sample AVCAM from apple found error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

When I tried sample AVCAM swift with Xcode Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q). I found errors.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP",
>   referenced from:
>         __T05AVCam20CameraViewControllerC12capturePhoto33_F53A4CF98D799BDDCA6C04BA14C549A1LLySo8UIButtonCFyycfU_
>   in CameraViewController.o
>   "__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0Says6UInt32VGfg",
>   referenced from:
>         __T05AVCam20CameraViewControllerC12capturePhoto33_F53A4CF98D799BDDCA6C04BA14C549A1LLySo8UIButtonCFyycfU_
>   in CameraViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

What is the problem? and How can fix that?

Comment: your library does not support for simulator, check once in device

Comment: I will try your solution. I will update later

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried building without device it doesn't work. Now I tried build with device some problem. Do you know how to fixed it?

Comment: wht is the problem

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is same problem. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694242/xcode-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I just updated to Xcode Beta 5 because you have to be on the latest version to upload to the App Store and started getting this error too. Worked fine on Beta 3.

Comment: @WernerKratochwil Yes it is duplicate but I post 4 day ago. but I posted first. I tried search no one ask. Andrew Herbert Solve my question

Comment: This issue seems to be back in Xcode 9 GM?

Comment: @gbhall I too am experiencing this in Xcode 9 GM. the above works as a workaround tho!

Comment: @aBikis please see the official workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861760/333733

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Update 15 Sept 2017:

Official response from Apple:

> Our apologies. For apps using Swift 3.2 or Swift 4.0, several
>   AVFoundation capture APIs (public extensions on external protocol)
>   were inadvertently marked private in Xcode 9.   The following
>   AVFoundation API are temporarily unavailable:
>
> - `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces`
> - `AVCaptureDevice.supportedFlashModes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>
>   As a workaround you can use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API
>     by prepending each API with double underscore (`__`). For example,
>     change `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to
>     `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.

I can confirm using `__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` fixes the build errors.

E.g.

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810#259270

---

### Update 14 Sept 2017:

Issue reoccurs in **Xcode 9.0 GM (9A235)**.

Filed new bug report for reference: `rdar://34420979`

---

**Previous:**

Update: Fixed in Xcode Beta 6.

Filed a bug report `rdar://33935456` for Xcode Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q).

Comment: Thank you for your update. The problem is gone no. I will update the accepted answer. Xcode Beta 5 and 6 Still problem If you want just fix with Xcode beta 5 or 6, then you can try Andrew Herbert.

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q) definitely has a problem with AVCam Swift revision 2017-06-06. Fortunately the problem is isolated to these three lines in `CameraViewController.swift`:

```
if !photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.isEmpty {
    photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!]
}
```

Comment out the above code and AVCam will compile and run fine on a device running the latest iOS 11 beta.

Comment: For anyone experiencing this issue with Xcode 9's GM build, see [my answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202917/3830465).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an Xcode bug. The sample code builds fine in Xcode 9.0 beta (9M136h). Reported to Apple as rdar://33903950.

Update: Radar is now closed. Issue is fixed in Xcode 9.0 Beta 6 (9M214v).

Comment: Filed a bug too report too (33935456). Using `Xcode Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)`.

Comment: Yes. It is bug. Andrew Herbert has solved my question.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add AVFoundation to linked frameworks (Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries)

Comment: have the same problem and tried the above, but did not work for me. Am I doing something wrong?