# Xcode Error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm running Swift 4 and Xcode 9 beta. I get this errors and I have no idea how to solve it. I don't even know what does that mean..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
      __T014InstagramClone26CustomCameraViewControllerC23cameraBtn_TouchUpInsideyypF in CustomCameraViewController.o
  "__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0Says6UInt32VGfg", referenced from:
      __T014InstagramClone26CustomCameraViewControllerC23cameraBtn_TouchUpInsideyypF in CustomCameraViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45668293/6541007)(not solved). May be a bug of iOS (Simulator) SDK 11 on Xcode 9 beta (5 only?). Send a bug report soon and wait for the fixed version. Until fixed, you may need to comment out some parts of your code.

Comment: Appears to be Xcode beta bug. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668293/try-sample-avcam-from-apple-found-error

Comment: maybe downgrading to an earlier beta version might be the solution for now. Has anybody tried something similar on a different beta?

Answer (score 1):

On my case, I've called `settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()` and I got that error.

Eventually the solution was calling a different initialiser. i.e:

```
settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your project probably isn't linking against AVFoundation. Click on your project at the top of the Project Navigator, select your target, and click "Build Phases." In the "Link Binary with Libraries" phase, click the Add button, select AVFoundation from the list, and add it. This should cause your project to build normally.

Comment: I've tried this, still get the same error really. I cleared and ran the project again, still get the same errors.

Comment: same with me, I still get the errors on both device and simulator