# Sample AVCAM - Swift Xcode v9

Tags: swift

```
 @objc func didTapCameraView() {
    self.cameraView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.spinner.isHidden = false
    self.spinner.startAnimating()

    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType, kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160, kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]

    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat

    if flashControlState == .off {
        settings.flashMode = .off
    } else {
        settings.flashMode = .on
    }
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

I'm getting this error when I run the app using Xcode 9 swift 4

> **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
>   "__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP",
>   referenced from:
>         __T014vision_app_dev8CameraVCC06didTapD4ViewyyF in CameraVC.o   "__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0Says6UInt32VGfg",
>   referenced from:
>         __T014vision_app_dev8CameraVCC06didTapD4ViewyyF in CameraVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: Getting the same error

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202060/apple-mach-o-linker-ld-error-group-with-swift-3-xcode-9-gm

Answer (score 1):

Try changing 
`let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!`

to

`let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!`

***Apple accidentally made some AVFoundation API external protocols private hence the 2 undescores `_` before the methods to access them.

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810#259270

Source: [Try Sample AVCAM from apple found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668293/try-sample-avcam-from-apple-found-error)