# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group with Swift 3 & Xcode 9 GM

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, avfoundation

This was running fine till GM Xcode (and iOS 11).  Now I get these errors:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group
  "__T0So20AVCapturePhotoOutputC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
xxxxxxxxxx

"__T012AVFoundation37_AVCapturePhotoOutputSwiftNativeTypesPAAE012availableRawc11PixelFormatG0SaySo8NSNumberCGfg", referenced from:
xxxxxxxxx

"  "__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
xxxxxxxxxx

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Some of the lines it's pointing at are:

```
photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: OSType(self.photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!))
photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!.uint32Value,
                                                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 3024, kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 3024]
```

Also:

```
let rawFormat = self.photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!.uint32Value
photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: OSType(rawFormat),
                            processedFormat: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG,
                                              AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [AVVideoQualityKey : 1.0]] as [String : Any])
            photoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: photoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!.uint32Value,
                                                kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 3024,
                                                kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 3024]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update 15 Sept 2017:

Official response from Apple:

> Our apologies. For apps using Swift 3.2 or Swift 4.0, several
>   AVFoundation capture APIs (public extensions on external protocol)
>   were inadvertently marked private in Xcode 9.   The following
>   AVFoundation API are temporarily unavailable:
>
> - `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces`
> - `AVCaptureDevice.supportedFlashModes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>
>   As a workaround you can use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API
>     by prepending each API with double underscore (`__`). For example,
>     change `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to
>     `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.

I can confirm using `__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` fixes the build errors.

E.g.

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810#259270

Comment: Thanks buddy for such a lovely post. It saves my day.

Answer (score 4):

This bug was present in earlier beta versions of Xcode 9 (`rdar://33903950`) and was apparently resolved (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668293/try-sample-avcam-from-apple-found-error)). It's returned for me as well in the GM build. I'm filing `rdar ://34412264` about this issue. Hopefully it's resolved soon and another GM build is related; until then, I you can continue working using earlier beta versions of Xcode 9, but won't be able to release that work. This is a total show-stopper for my app.

Edit: I'll also mention that commenting lines pertaining to `AVCapturePhotoSettings`' preview properties (`previewPhotoFormat`, `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`, `kCVPixelBufferWidthKey`, etc.) allows your project to build. If it's possible for you to omit these in your project, this may be a good workaround for now.

Comment: Wow.  Not a single way around this? Just not right!

Comment: @Gizmodo I'd recommend duping the new bug report to bring attention to it.

Comment: @JohnWickham please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861760/333733 to reference my bug report, I'm updating my bug report to reference yours too.

Answer (score 4):

I've changed:

```
if cameraOutput.supportedFlashModes.contains(NSNumber(value: flashMode.rawValue)) {
```

to:

```
if cameraOutput.__supportedFlashModes.contains(NSNumber(value: flashMode.rawValue)) {
```

and

```
let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```

to

```
let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```

and the app started.