# Weird compile error with AVCapture after updating to Xcode 9 / Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

I have a normal `UIViewController` that uses `AVCapturePhoto` in which I create a custom capture controller.

Everything worked properly until I update to `Xcode 9` and converted my code to `Swift 4` and now when I try to compile I get this compiling-error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
>         __T05Union16CameraControllerC18handleCapturePhotoyyF in CameraController.o
>     "__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0Says6UInt32VGfg", referenced from:
>         __T05Union16CameraControllerC18handleCapturePhotoyyF in CameraController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And in the error tray this message is shown:

> Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

Any hint what may be causing this ?

**Updated Info**

Here's a Xcode 9 print screen of the error-log. Hope it helps on the compiling error solution.

[image]

**Edit**

Just performing some tests -- if I comment the class code, the compile-error goes away.

Is there anything wrong in the following `class` implementation that I'm missing in `Swift 4` ??

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class CameraController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    let dismissButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "right_arrow_shadow").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismiss), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let capturePhotoButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "capture_photo").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCapturePhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        transitioningDelegate = self
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupHUD()
    }


    // hiddes the status bar
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }

    //MARK: General funcs
    fileprivate func setupCaptureSession() {
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        //1. setup inputs - camera
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch let err {
            print("Could not setup camera input:", err)
        }
        //2. setup outputs
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(output) {
            captureSession.addOutput(output)
        }
        //3.setup output preview
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)      
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        // starts the inputs/outputs
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }


    fileprivate func setupHUD() {
        // botão de captura
        view.addSubview(capturePhotoButton)
        capturePhotoButton.anchor(top: nil, left: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 24, paddingRight: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
        capturePhotoButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // dismiss button
        view.addSubview(dismissButton)
        dismissButton.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddinfLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 50)
    }


    @objc func handleCapturePhoto() {
        // processes the captured photo
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        guard let preview = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first else { return }
        settings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: preview]
        output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }


    @objc func handleDismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // Camera delegate
    func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {
        // access the captured image
        let imageData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer!, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer!)
        let previewImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)

        // shows the image
        let containerView = PreviewPhotoContainerView()
        containerView.previewImageView.image = previewImage

        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddinfLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    }   
}
```

Comment: Your undefined symbol demangles to `protocol witness table for __ObjC.AVCapturePhotoSettings : AVFoundation._AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypes in AVFoundation`

Comment: @KevinBallard sorry but I'm kinda lost on your comment.
You're saying I need to conform to the AVCapturePhotoSettings protocol?

Comment: I'm confused why this is a duplicate to the other question. This error showed up when testing on my iphone7. The one who flagged this as duplicate is drunk! I found several ways on fixing my problem without the use of that code, #if arch(x86_64)

Comment: @r_19 I think Matt flagged this as a duplicate, who is a ‘respected’ iOS user here on SO. The duplicate he pointed to was just related to the ‘arch(x86_64)’ he might have misread the post. Anyway I’m curious to check how you overpass this issue as you said.

Comment: One way is by adding 2 `_` (underscores) before, to some of AVFoundation classes that apple accidentally made private. For example change `settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first else` to `settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first else`.  

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810#259270

Comment: The correct duplicate of this error is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668293/try-sample-avcam-from-apple-found-error

Comment: yeah, I've read that Apple statement that they released some APIs functions as private by mistake. They might correct it soon with the next Xcode update probably :D thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to solve this issue.

Somehow , with Xcode 9 you cannot have "free" code implemented that will not work on iOS Simulator.

The error - after solving it off - was pretty simple.

I cannot use the camera in the simulator, because it will not work.

I think Xcode could give more useful error information.

In order to solve this, in my `CameraController class` I had to edit my `handleCapturePhoto()` function.

I has to check that if the used architecture wasn't `x86_64` (simulator) , then I could present the camera output.

This is the function solved state:

```
@objc func handleCapturePhoto() {
    // processes the captured photo
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

    // doesn't show in the simulator
    #if (!arch(x86_64))
        guard let preview = settings.previewPhotoFormat?.first else { return }
        settings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: preview]
        output.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    #endif
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: This will let you build and run your project but is not the true solution to the problem. I tried this and replaced the other solutions I found, without using `#if (!arch(x86_64))`, and it did not behave as expected. But, if it works for you, it works for you. Just be cautioned that this solution, may solve that issue but replace with a new problem

Comment: It’s pretty simple. If the device is the simulator - don’t open the camera. This is just for testing, in the release version I can delete the #ifdef anyways if I wish to

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried this solution on my iphone 7 and it DID remove the compile error but it DID NOT behave the same way as expected. So, just make sure all of your features are working as expected. If so, you're good.

Comment: @r_19 ohh... it did work then thoug. I misinterpreted what you’ve said. Sorry

Comment: This is actually a known bug in xcode 9, apples official response is to use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API by prepending each API with double underscore (`__`).  For example, change `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.

Comment: @ChristopherLarsen yes I know (now); I hope they’ll fix it with the next Xcode update because it is pretty annoying though

Comment: @ChristopherLarsen will this create a problem while we submit app for review ?

Comment: @vishaldharankar probably not, at least I hope not, but on the release version you can remove the #ifdef since it’s only for simulators. I’ll probably remove that check in the release version and add it only for development purposes

Comment: @IvanCantarino asking about these lines AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces to AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces.

Comment: @vishaldharankar ohh sorry, I thought you were regarding the topic itself. My bad

Comment: @vishaldharankar Shouldn't, the solution came from apple. I've implemented it in code that's passed review already. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810